# Cant use ofstream as field in c++

Tags: c++

I am creating a class for writing file in c++, and i have this code so far,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class FileWriter
{
private:
    bool isLittleEndian;
    ofstream file;

public:
FileWriter(string fileName) : file("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary)
    {
        int i = 1;
        char *p = (char *)&i;

        if(p[0] == 1)
            isLittleEndian = true;
    }

    void writeByte()
    {

    }

    void writeShort()
    {

    }

    void writeInt()
    {

    }

    void writeLong()
    {

    }

    void writeUnsignedByte()
    {

    }

    void writeUnsignedShort()
    {

    }

    void writeUnsignedInt()
    {

    }

    void writeUnsignedLong()
    {

    }

    void writeFloat()
    {

    }

    void writeDouble()
    {

    }

    void writeString()
    {

    }

    void closeFile()
    {
        file.close();
    }
};

int main()
{
    FileWriter writer = FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Test.bin");
    writer.closeFile();
    return 0;
}
```

but for some reason, it wont let me have an ofstream field, and when i try it says, `Error  1   error C2248: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>' c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\bytetests\bytetests\bytetests.cpp  25  1`  I need this because functions in my class need to manipulate this stream.  I don't see why this so hard to do.

Comment: You shouldn't your code, it makes all the answers irrelevant. But there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong now, so the error must be elsewhere.

Comment: well then why wont it work, can you compile it

Comment: I can compile [this simplified version](http://ideone.com/Kltt4g).

Comment: @Popgalop I updated my answer which should fix your remaining problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't copy or assign an `std::ofstream`, which means you can't do this:

```
file = openedFile;
```

You need to either initialize it correctly, or move-copy-assign.

Initialization (preferred option):

```
FileWriter(string fileName) : file("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary)
{ 
  ...
}
```

Move-copy assignment:

```
file = std::move(openedFile);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `std::ofstream::open` method:

```
file.open("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Comment: @Popgalop I have added some explanation.

Comment: i still get this error Error 1 error C2248: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>' c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\bytetests\bytetests\bytetests.cpp 87 1 ByteTests

Comment: @Popgalop I had a typo in my answer, See edit. And [simplified example](http://ideone.com/Kltt4g).

Comment: i updates my code in my question with your suggested edits but i still get an error

Answer (score 2):

You can just open the existing object:

```
file.open("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

And you need to avoid calling (or at least requiring) the copy-ctor of your class. Change

```
FileWriter writer = FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Test.bin");
```

to:

```
FileWriter writer("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Test.bin");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
file = openedFile;
```

There is only one `operator=` defined for `basic_ofstream`, the move-assignment operator. The copy-assignment operator is implicitly deleted, and so this code will not work.

You need to use the member-initializer list to initialize `file` with the path:

```
FileWriter(std::string fileName)
    : file(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I still just get this error  2 IntelliSense: "std::basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &_Right) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (declared at line 1034 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\fstream") is inaccessible c:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ByteTests\ByteTests\ByteTests.cpp 13 11 ByteTests

Comment: @Popgalop Remove the original `ofstream openFile(...)` and `file = openedFile`

Comment: Error 1 error C2248: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>' c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\bytetests\bytetests\bytetests.cpp 84 1 ByteTests

Comment: @Popgalop I don't think it has anything to do with the code you just showed us...